# Take all $_GET and add to end of url?

Tags: php

I have a bunch of methods of sorting date=desc,etc,etc and they are posted via a `$_GET` I want to take all the `$_GET` variables (`$_GET['anythingatall']`) and transform them from `$_GET['variable]=blah` to `&variable=blah`

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You mean $variable=blah?

Comment: No I want to get what ever the key name of the $_GET is (for example date for $_GET['date] and the value and put them into &keyname=value)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are interested in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, I think. This will contain everything passed in `$_GET` but in the format you desire.

Answer (score 7):

This might work for you

```
 $string = http_build_query($_GET, null, '&')
```

Alex's solution should work too, and admittedly cleaner.  If you wanted to create a query string from any other array using http_build_query should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

If all you're wanting to do is pass on the existing query string (which is available in `$_GET`), you can use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, which will be exactly what you're looking for, a query string representation of the `$_GET` array (assuming you didn't change it)

See the [PHP documentation on the `$_SERVER` superglobal.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 0):

you may want to take a look at http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php